# ValidateCredentials conditions to return false

Tags: c#, active-directory, userprincipal, principalcontext

I'm using PrincipalContext's *ValidateCredentials* method to authenticate into Active Directory, but for some reason it returns false despite the password being correct and not expired. I've checked for the state of the user with *UserPrincipal*, but despite the user being enabled and not locked, it still returns false. I also made sure that the last password set wasn't past its expiration date.

Are there other factors that make ValidateCredentials return false?

Code used:

```cs
bool expired = false;
bool blocked = false;
bool disabled = false;
int failedLogins;

Resultado resul = new Resultado();
PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Config.ActiveDirectory.Server,
                                                                            Directory,
                                                                            Config.ActiveDirectory.User,
                                                                            Config.ActiveDirectory.Pass);
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, userName);

if (user != null)
{
    disabled = (user.Enabled == null || !user.Enabled.Value);
    blocked = user.IsAccountLockedOut();
    expired = user.LastPasswordSet == null || DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(user.LastPasswordSet.Value).Days >= Config.ActiveDirectory.MaxPassAge;

    failedLogins = user.BadLogonCount; 


    if (domainContext.ValidateCredentials(userName, password))
        resul.ResultCode = 0;
    else
    {
        user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, userName);

        if (disabled)
            resul.ResultCode = 7;
        else if (blocked)
            resul.ResultCode = 3;
        else if (failedLogins != user.BadLogonCount)
            resul.ResultCode = 2;
        else
            resul.ResultCode = 4;
    }
}
else
    resul.ResultCode = 1;
return resul;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the account expiration date using the [`AccountExpirationDate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.authenticableprincipal.accountexpirationdate) property.

Also, check if the password must be changed on next logon. The [`LastPasswordSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.authenticableprincipal.lastpasswordset) property will be `null` if that's the case.

There is also a note in the [documentation for `ValidateCredentials`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext.validatecredentials) that might be relevant:

> The `userName` argument must take the form *username* (for example, *mcampbell*) rather than *domain\username* or *username@domain*.

Have you tried logging into a computer with that username and password? That is the best way to determine if `ValidateCredentials` is lying to you or not.

Curious: why are you setting `user` to the same thing again in your `else` block? That seems unnecessary.

Comment: AccountExpirationDate is set to null, it doesn't expire.
LastPasswordSet wasn't null (I checked during debugging).
Can ValidateCredentials outright lie? I haven't logon using the username and pass to avoid creating unecessary data in our company computers.

if I don't update *user*, it won't refresh the amount of BadLogonCount, which I need to check if the password is incorrect.

Comment: Any logon restrictions on the account? If you look at the account in AD Users and Computers, this is on the Account tab of the user, under the "Logon Hours" or "Log On To" buttons.

Comment: It might also be the format of `userName` that you are passing to it. I've updated my answer.

Comment: It doesn't have either Logon Hours and userName is passed without specifying the domain.